# How to convert &lt;br&gt; to <br> in xslt/xquery

Tags: java, xslt, xquery, soa, osb

I am getting this request

```
<description>V1&lt;br&gt;V2&lt;br&gt;V3</description>
```

and I need to convert it into below code and send it to target system:

```
V1<br>V2<br>V3
```

How I can convert it in xslt/query?

Comment: A simple selection of `<description>`'s text will convert `&lt;` and `&gt;` back to `<` and `>`.  Output _text/plain_, not _text/xml_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to do any conversion. The string value of the `<description>` element is the string `V1<br>V2<br>V3`. Your only problem is to avoid it being converted to something else, which will happen for example if you try to output it using the XML serialization method.

So it depends a bit on what you mean by "send it to the target system".

With XSLT, typically you would want to output the result using the text output method.

With XQuery, a query that returns a string to the calling application will do the right thing.

Comment: target system/3rd party need description like this V1<br>V2<br>V3, they dont understand this format V1&lt;br&gt;V2&lt;br&gt;V3  which OSB sending so, as per ur comment,  it will take automatically by expected format as V1<br>V2<br>V3 else need to do any conversion before sending to them at OSB side

Answer (score 0):

use `disable-output-escaping="yes"` like below

```
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: The question was edited so that original XML tags reappeared. You might reconsider your answer - not your fault.